# request for member 'atributoOuDecisao' in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, operadores

Erro na inicialização de arvore, o problema com as variáveis categoria e `atributoOuDecisao`.

```
typedef struct node {
    int categoria;
    int atributoOuDecisao;
    struct node *prox;
    struct node *lista;
} No;

No *criaArvore(void){
    No *inicio = (No*)malloc(sizeof(No));
    inicio.atributoOuDecisao = NULL;
    inicio.categoria = NULL;
    inicio->lista = NULL;
    inicio->prox = NULL;
    printf ("inicio criado");
    return inicio;
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Quando usa um ponteiro para uma estrutura o operador correto para acessar os membros é sempre o `->`. Além disso os tipos inteiros devem ser inicializados com 0 e não com `NULL`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct node {
    int categoria;
    int atributoOuDecisao;
    struct node *prox;
    struct node *lista;
} No;

No *criaArvore(void){
    No *inicio = malloc(sizeof(No));
    inicio->atributoOuDecisao = 0;
    inicio->categoria = 0;
    inicio->lista = NULL;
    inicio->prox = NULL;
    printf ("inicio criado");
    return inicio;
}

int main() {
    criaArvore();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/TEUwsg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vfmsdffg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/StructPointer.c).